# Common Lisp: flush standard output

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, stdout

Trying to learn lisp (and I guess emacs along with it).
I was wondering how you would go about clearing the output and replacing it.
Could be in a LISP repl, or an emacs buffer.
Something akin to the following in python.

```
def go(r):
    for i in range(r):
        sys.stdout.write("\rDoing %i" % i)
        sys.stdout.flush()
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For common lisp, you are looking for

[`Functions FINISH-OUTPUT, FORCE-OUTPUT, CLEAR-OUTPUT`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_finish.htm):

`finish-output`, `force-output`, and `clear-output` exercise control over the internal handling of buffered stream output.

- `finish-output` attempts to ensure that any buffered output sent to output-stream has reached its destination, and then returns.
- `force-output` initiates the emptying of any internal buffers but does not wait for completion or acknowledgment to return.
- `clear-output` attempts to abort any outstanding output operation in progress in order to allow as little output as possible to continue to the destination.

and

[`Variables *DEBUG-IO*, *ERROR-OUTPUT*, *QUERY-IO*, *STANDARD-INPUT*, *STANDARD-OUTPUT*, *TRACE-OUTPUT*`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/v_debug_.htm)

- The value of `*debug-io*`, called debug I/O, is a stream to be used for interactive debugging purposes.
- The value of `*error-output*`, called error output, is a stream to which warnings and non-interactive error messages should be sent.
- The value of `*query-io*`, called query I/O, is a bidirectional stream to be used when asking questions of the user. The question should be output to this stream, and the answer read from it.
- The value of `*standard-input*`, called standard input, is a stream that is used by many operators as a default source of input when no specific input stream is explicitly supplied.
- The value of `*standard-output*`, called standard output, is a stream that is used by many operators as a default destination for output when no specific output stream is explicitly supplied.
- The value of `*trace-output*`, called trace output, is the stream on which traced functions (see trace) and the time macro print their output.

Emacs Lisp is quite different, you might want to start here: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Output-Functions.html